# How to deal with mysql server downtime?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to make a file that is hosted on my site (for ex `site.com/db.sql`) that my website will pull from when my `mysql` server is down?

I recently signed up for `Fatcow` to realize that their `MYSQL` server is down more than half the time, and I have a simple database that I need pulling from.

I do plan on leaving Fatcow but I need a temporary solution until I can switch hosting.

Comment: Use SQLite as a replacement.

Comment: your at a host whose mysql server is down that often and haven't moved?

Comment: I just signed up a couple days ago - and I am just experiencing this. I paid for 2 years in advance, which was a stupid idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use SQLLite until you leave FatCow.

It's very easy and simple to setup.

Here's a tutorial on how to read from and write to a SQLLite db file using PHP. http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitephp/